# dbt depends on a source not found

Tags: dbt

Could you please help me with this issue?

```
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model metrics_model (models\example\metrics_model.sql)
  Model 'model.test_project.metrics_model' (models\example\metrics_model.sql) depends on a source named 'automate.metrics' which was not found
```

I am having this monotonous error, which I have not been able to solve.

Many thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL database please check if the sources.yml file is defined as follows:

```
version: 2
sources:
  - name: name_of the source
    schema: name_of_the_schema
    quoting:
      database: false
      schema: false
      identifier: false
    loader: stitch
    tables:
      - name: name_of_table1
      - name: name_of_table2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `automate.metrics` table missing from the database (either the dbt project’s target database or a different database on the same server). There should be a `source.yml` or `automate.yml` file somewhere in your project that defines the source. FYI `automate` is the schema name and `metrics` is the table name.

1. If the source yml file specifies a database for the `automate` schema, query that database to make sure that the `metrics` table exists in the `automate` schema.
2. If the source yml file doesn’t list a database, then that schema / table should exist in the dbt project’s target database. You can see what the target database is by looking at the profile for your project setup in `~/.dbt/profiles.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing this in your dev environment? It's possible that you've not run `dbt run` after creating the `automate.metrics` which is preventing `metrics_model` from referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you put source config in the right yaml file. I encountered this issue and tried every solutions including above one. Then finally I forgot to put suffix .yml in the source file, and when dbt can't locate source config in that file.